# Why do my div's overlap with each of them at 50vh & 50vw?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The four boxes that I made are overlapping, even though they are all set to a height of 50vh and a width of 50vw. Why is this and how do I make them stop overlapping?

[image: overlapping divs]

[image: overlapping divs with inspect]

**HTML (React):**

```
<div className={styles['policyContainer']}>
    <div className={styles["foreignPoliciesContainer"]}></div>
    <div className={styles["taxPoliciesContainer"]}></div>
    <div className={styles["lawOrderPoliciesContainer"]}></div>
    <div className={styles["econTransPoliciesContainer"]}></div>
</div>
```

**CSS (Module):**

```
.policyContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -99;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.foreignPoliciesContainer {
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -99;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #000;
}

.taxPoliciesContainer {
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -99;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #000;
}

.lawOrderPoliciesContainer {
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -99;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #000;
}

.econTransPoliciesContainer {
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -99;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #000;
}
```

I tried setting the height and width of all four to 50%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border width is impacting the final width and height of your boxes. You can set the `box-sizing` property for your boxes to `border-box` to change this.

```
.policyContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -99;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.foreignPoliciesContainer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -99;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #000;
}

.taxPoliciesContainer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -99;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #000;
}

.lawOrderPoliciesContainer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -99;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #000;
}

.econTransPoliciesContainer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -99;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #000;
}
```